# How to show a line being drawn from one point to another?

Tags: flutter, line, paint

I used canvas.drawLine to show a line but I want user to be able to see it being drawn from one point to another and also, if possible, control the duration of the animation.
(something like progress bar but this is my custom widget)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an [AnimationController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) to control the animation duration.

To draw the line "step by step" you can use a [Tween](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html) (linear interpolation between a beginning and ending value).

Then you just need to pass the current progress to your line painter and calculate the new width/height on each `paint()` when you call `canvas.drawLine`.

Working example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Line extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _LineState();
}

class _LineState extends State<Line> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double _progress = 0.0;
  Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000), vsync: this);

    animation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _progress = animation.value;
        });
      });

    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(painter: LinePainter(_progress));
  }
}

class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  Paint _paint;
  double _progress;

  LinePainter(this._progress) {
    _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(0.0, 0.0), Offset(size.width - size.width * _progress, size.height - size.height * _progress), _paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(LinePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate._progress != _progress;
  }
}
```

Then use it like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Line animation'),
        leading: new Icon(Icons.insert_emoticon),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SizedBox(height: 200, width: 200, child: Line()),
    );
  }
}
```

The line will be drawn in the sized box from `0,0` to `200,200` in 3 seconds.

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comments @pskink, I have made `Line` a widget but of course this is not mandatory. I'm not a flutter expert and I have proposed **a** solution, maybe it does not use the minimum code but I think is understandable, easy to read and efficient. Feel free to post another answer if you think it can improve my answer and benefit to the community :)

Comment: User can still change the accepted answer afterwards if he/she thinks yours is better.

Comment: That was just great! Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 9):

use a custom `CustomPainter` class that passes `Animation` to the `super` constructor - that way the `CustomPainter#paint()` method is automatically called on each "frame" of the animation:

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List points;
  Paint linePaint;
  Animation anim;
  Size size = Size.zero;

  MyCustomPainter(Animation anim) : super(repaint: anim) {
    linePaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 16;
    this.anim = anim;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (size != this.size) {
      print('new size $size');
      this.size = size;
      Rect r = (Offset.zero & size).deflate(linePaint.strokeWidth * 1.5);
      points = [
        [r.topLeft, r.bottomLeft], // begins
        [r.bottomLeft, r.topRight], // ends
      ].map((o) => anim.drive(Tween(begin: o[0], end: o[1]))).toList();
    }
    canvas.drawLine(points[0].value, points[1].value, linePaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

the complete working code would look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AnimatedPainterTest());
}

class AnimatedPainterTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            AnimationController controller = AnimationController(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              vsync: Scaffold.of(context),
            );
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => controller.forward(from: 0.0),
                  child: Text('press me to start the animation'),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox.expand(
                    child: CustomPaint(
                      painter: MyCustomPainter(controller),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the result is:

[image]