# Flutter Custom Painter Draw Loop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

How can I create an infinite loop that allows me to update the canvas inside a CustomPainter widget in flutter? I tried looking at the Flame game engine source code, but it's taking me too long to decode the functionality, I'm still relatively new to flutter. Could someone with experience point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: check optional `repaint` parameter that you can pass to `CustomPainter` constructor - the painter will repaint whenever `repaint` notifies its listeners

Comment: @pskink I noticed that but I don't know how how these Listeners are used yet. The concept is foreign to me.

Comment: just pass any kind of `Listenable` - it can be `AnimationController` for example

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286551/2252830) you have a woriking example

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Ill try them asap and come back with an answer hopefully. @pskink

Comment: Ill check it out asap @RichardHeap