# CustomPaint instruct repaint with animation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have a `CustomPaint` and an `Animation` and I want the custompaint to repaint according to the animation value. This is what I have so far

```
controller = AnimationController(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  vsync: this,
);

animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 0.9).animate(CurvedAnimation(
    parent: controller, curve: Curves.ease, reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut))
  ..addListener(() {
    setState(() {
        customView.setSomeProperty(animation.value)
    });
  });

_controller.forward().orCancel;
```

Yet this does not call the paint method of customPaint. there's also no method to issue a paint yourself.

So how can I animate my custompaint with an animation?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286551/2252830

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show a line being drawn from one point to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270549/how-to-show-a-line-being-drawn-from-one-point-to-another)